# use redis set key value nothing happen in node

Tags: node.js, redis

```js
const client = redis.createClient(port, host)
client.connect()
client.on('connect', function() {
  consola.success('Connected!')
  client.set('framework', 'ReactJS', function(err, reply) {
    client.get('framework', function(err, value) {
      console.log('value', value)
    })
  })
})
```

in my console only print 'Connected' and nothing else happened,could somebody tell my why

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try once with the following code?

```
const redis = require("redis");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const client = redis.createClient(port, host);
client.connect();
const setAsync = promisify(client.set).bind(client);
const getAsync = promisify(client.get).bind(client);
setAsync('framework', 'ReactJS');
const framewrok = await getAsync("framework")
console.log(framework); //should log "ReactJs"
```